# Sci-fi fantasy novel with a beast with a cat face trapped on another planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

My brother and I are trying to find a novel we read in the 90s when we were small children.

We can't remember most of the plot, but it was a sci-fi fantasy novel, there were androids and space travel, and the plot centered around this secret ("eternal"?) beast with a cat face trapped inside a dome or a force field or something on another planet? They either had to free this beast, or keep him from breaking free, and I think he was psychic. There was an android named Sarah, I think, and she was in love with a human. One of the characters went off on a monologue about Gilgamesh at some point, too.

It was part of a series. I'd love to find this book and read it again.

Comment: possible duplicate? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175610/sci-fi-story-about-an-astronaut-and-telepathic-feline-like-aliens

Comment: possible duplicate? [Identifying a story about a girl named Sarah who finds out she is a robot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4768/identifying-a-story-about-a-girl-named-sarah-who-finds-out-she-is-a-robot)